# Is it possible to set up JavaScript to capture when a button is clicked that's from an external site iframe?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, button, iframe

Have an iframe on a Visualforce page that's src is from an external site. The iframe has a button that's used to send a recording off via email from that external site. I'm trying to see if it's possible to add some JavaScript to capture the DateTime when that button is clicked. Been getting some unreliable data back from the external site about when users are sending the email, so we want to see if we can capture that on our end instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a listener with JS to the iFrame

ex.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('myIFrame');
iframe.contentDocument.body.addEventListener('mouseup', Handler);

function Handler() {
    alert(new Date());
}
```

Comment: Rather inaccurate to check on the entire iframe itself for a mouseup event, but an interesting idea. I'll give it more consideration.

Comment: To get the button itself, can also get the contentWindow.document of the iFrame and look for the element itself